# AES.block_size что это?

Tags: python, aes

Вообщем есть 2-е таких строки

```
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```

И хотелось понять что за AES.block_size, его размер нигде не указывается и сколько байт он содержит?

Answer (score 0):

Симметричный алгоритм блочного шифрования (размер блока 128 бит, ключ 128/192/256 бит)

Comment: А не могли бы вы обьяснить выполнение данного кода
    def pad(self, text):
        return text + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)